# Why does Kotlin have both Regex and Pattern classes?

Tags: regex, kotlin

It seems like there's significant overlap between the behaviors of the Kotlin standard library's Regex and Pattern classes.  Why the duplication?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Yeah, so why did Kotlin also add Regex?

Comment: @JulianA. Kotlin supports more backends than just the JVM, so it reimplements (usually by just wrapping backend-specific implementations) many standard classes for compatibility. It also allows users to use more idiomatic APIs for the same features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin *has* `Regex` class in its own standard library and *can use* `java.util.regex.Pattern` class from the JDK standard library when a Kotlin program is compiled for JVM target platform. In the other target platforms only the former class is available.

The `Regex` class provides a subset of regex features that is feasible to implement in all platforms and exposes these features in a way that is more idiomatic for Kotlin.